# How to acces formData value pairs on Express server (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, multipartform-data

I am trying to read formData that I send to my server. First I append something to a `formData` object. It looks like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('email', this.email);
```

My post request looks like this:

```
axios.post('/api/auth/register', formData, {
  headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
  }
})
```

My backend route:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  //this does log the email 'key', but the value is empty
  console.log('email: ', req.body)
  res.status(200).end()
})
```

**How can I 'access' the email value on the server?**

I've tried parsing it first with

`email = JSON.parse(req.body.email);`

But whatever I do, I cannot seem to get the value that I send...

I do have bodyParser installed. This is in my `app.js`

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Comment: For Express, you need the package "body-parser". Did you install it?

Comment: Yes, this is in my app.js `app.use(bodyParser.json()) app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It has to be formData because I'm also sending a file with the request.

Comment: [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is like the de-facto solution for handling multipart/form-data. You can take a look at [formidable](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable) also